# even after converting it to varchar it is giving error: Error converting data type varchar to float,

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT a.[Emp_No],
       a.[Emp_Name],
       a.[Band],
       b.[Max_Exp] AS Max_Yrs_Experience,
       CASE WHEN a.Performance_Score = 0 AND (a.Status_Active > 0 OR a.Status_New > 0)
            THEN CONVERT(varchar, 0)
            WHEN a.Performance_Score > 0
            THEN [Performance_Score]
            ELSE 'No History Data Found'
       END AS Performance_Score
INTO #EXPER
FROM #PERFORMANCE a, #agg_exp b
WHERE a.[Emp_No] = b.[Emp_No]
ORDER BY Performance_Score DESC
```

> Error converting varchar to float.

I don't know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty you are having is due to that SQL Server requires that all posssible values generated in a `CASE` expression have the same type.  Since your `ELSE` uses text, which can't be converted to any numeric type, the only option is to convert the numbers to text.

```
CASE WHEN a.Performance_Score = 0 AND (a.Status_Active > 0 OR a.Status_New > 0)
     THEN CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), 0)                     -- zero as text
     WHEN a.Performance_Score > 0
     THEN CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), [Performance_Score])   -- performance score as text
     ELSE 'No History Data Found'                      -- this is already text
END AS Performance_Score
```

Going by the error message, I am assuming here that `[Performance Score]` is a float column.  If it be some other type, you would have to modify the call to `CONVERT()` appropriately.

Comment: Hi Tim,
I want performance score as an int only ,i.e., 
the first case  should give "New State" after fullfilling the condition
2nd case should give Performance_Score only (which is a numeric value)
otherwise  it will give 'No History Data Found'

please help

Comment: @SandhyaNegi You _can't_ mix text and pure numbers as the output of the same `CASE` expression.  The point I was trying to make is that you _can_ display numbers, but you need to first convert them to text.

Comment: please give an example how?

Comment: My answer is an example how.  The number zero is converted to text, but the text `No History Data Found` is used directly.